# Error when running Singularity container for R script

Tags: r, rgdal, singularity-container

I am building a Singularity container to run a custom R script for tree segmentation using the LidR software package.

I have written the Singularity definition file as such:

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:20.04

%setup
    touch test.R
    touch treeSeg_dalponte2016.R
    touch /home/ljeasson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so
    
%files
    test.R
    treeSeg_dalponte2016.R
    /home/ljeasson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so

%post
    # Disable interactivity, including region and time zone
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
    export DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true
        
    # Update apt and install necessary libraries and repositories
    apt update
    
    apt install -y build-essential r-base-core software-properties-common dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
    
    add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
    
    apt install -y libgdal-dev libgeos++-dev libudunits2-dev libproj-dev libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libfreetype6-dev libnode-dev libxt-dev libfftw3-dev
    
    apt clean
    
    
    # Install necessary R packages and dependencies
    R -e "install.packages('lidR', dependencies = TRUE)"
    R -e "install.packages('raster', dependencies = TRUE)"
    R -e "install.packages('sf', dependencies = TRUE)"
    R -e "install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE)"
    
    R -e "install.packages('rgdal', dependencies = TRUE, repos='https://cran.rstudio.com', configure.args=c('--with-gdal-config=/opt/conda/bin/gdal-config', '--with-proj-include=/opt/conda/include', '--with-proj-lib=/opt/conda/lib', '--with-proj-share=/opt/conda/share/proj/'))"
            
    R -e "install.packages('gdalUtils', dependencies = TRUE, repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')"
    
    
%test
    #!/bin/bash
    R --version
    Rscript test.R
    

%runscript
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "Arguments received: $*"
    Rscript treeSeg_dalponte2016.R $*
```

And build the container using `singularity build ga_container.sif ga_container.def`

The container builds without error, but when the container is run using `./ga_container <arguments>`, this error always occurs:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rgdal' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/ljeasson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  libgdal.so.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

I know that the error is occuring because it cannot find the image for Rgdal, even though it seems I've attached to the container in the `%setup` and `%files` section:

```
%setup
    touch test.R
    touch treeSeg_dalponte2016.R
    touch /home/ljeasson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so

%files
    test.R
    treeSeg_dalponte2016.R
    /home/ljeasson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so
```

If the error is from incorrect file attachment, how do I ensure that the Rgdal (and other similar libraries) are attached correctly within the Singularity container?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an environmental issue causing the image to look at your locally installed R modules instead of using the ones installed in the image. Perhaps in your `.Rprofile` or `R_LIBS`/`R_LIBS_USER`. Try running with `singularity run --cleanenv ...`, or temporarily moving your `.Rprofile` if you have one, and see if that fixes it. If not, I have a few other observations.

---

First, the `%setup` block is creating root owned, empty files on the host OS if they don't exist already. An empty `.so` file would certainly cause problems. For the majority of cases [you don't want to use `%setup`](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/definition_files.html#setup), as it directly modifies the host as root during `sudo singularity build`.

In the `%files` block you are copying the (potentially root owned/empty) to a path in the image that matches your home directory. Your [`$HOME` is automatically mounted](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#system-defined-bind-paths) when you run/exec/shell an image, which will hide any files in the image at that location. When adding files to an image, you should always put them in a place they are unlikely to get clobbered by a mount. `/opt/myapp` or something similar usually works well. Additionally, `test.R` and `treeSeg_dalponte2016.R` are copied to `/test.R` and `/treeSeg_dalponte2016.R` inside the container, but relative paths are used in `%runscript` and `%test`. Singularity run/exec will attempt to run from the first path that exists in the container: `$PWD` (implicitly mounted, but this can fail silently), then `$HOME` (also implicitly mounted and can fail silently), then `/`. You can use `singularity --verbose run ...` to see if anything isn't being mounted correctly and add `echo $PWD` to `%runscript` to see where it's running from.

In `%post` when you install the `rgdal` package, you specify several paths with `/opt/conda/...` but conda is not installed or configured in the image. I'm not familiar with `rgdal`, so don't know if that would cause problems or not though.